# Date exposed filter - Hour of day

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a content type with a "Date Repeat" field. I also have a view displaying events on a calendar.

What I need is to have some exposed filters to show only the events that happen between 2 and 6 pm (random example), any day of the week. The exposed date field only allow me to show content between 2015/12/1 12:00 to 2015/12/3 17:00 (random example).

This means it will show any content between that whole interval and I can't figure it out how to show content between 2 and 6, every day.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: That is a nice feature. A slider kind of widget will be ideal. Let us see.